# Python: create a polynomial of degree n

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a feature set

```
[x1,x2....xm]
```

Now I want to create polynomial feature set
What that means is that if degree is two, then I have the feature set

```
[x1.... xm,x1^2,x2^2...xm^2, x1x2, x1x3....x1,xm......xm-1x1....xm-1xm]
```

So it contains terms of only of order 2..
same is if order is three.. then you will have cubic terms as well..

How to do this?

Edit 1: I am working on a machine learning project where I have close to 7 features... and a non-linear regression on this linear features are giving ok result...Hence I thought that to get more number in features I can map these features to a higher dimension..
So one way is to consider polynomial order of the feature vector... 
Also generating x1*x1 is easy.. :) but getting the rest of the combinations are a bit tricky..

Can combinations give me x1x2x3 result if the order is 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
itertools.combinations(list, r)
```

where `list` is the feature set, and r is the order of desired polynomial features. Then multiply elements of the sublists given by the above. That should give you `{x1*x2, x1*x3, ...}`. You'll need to construct other ones, then union all parts.

[Edit] 
Better: `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list, r)` will nicely give sorted length-r tuples with repeated elements allowed.

Comment: `itertools.combinations(firstOrderFeatures, 3)` should give you all unique combinations of three first-order features. It will have `{x1, x2, x3}` but not the other 5 permutations of it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be itertools.combinations_with_replacement? The order 2 features are x1^2, x1x2, x2^2 and not (like combinations will give you) just x1x2.

Comment: You are right. `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list, r)` will nicely give sorted length-r tuples with repeated elements allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.product` to create all the possible sets of n values that are chosen from the original set; but keep in mind that this will generate `(x2, x1)` as well as `(x1, x2)`.

Similarly, `itertools.combinations` will produce sets without repetition or re-ordering, but that means you won't get `(x1, x1)` for example.

What exactly are you trying to do? What do you need these result values for? Are you sure you do want those `x1^2` type terms (what does it mean to have the same feature more than once)? What exactly is a "feature" in this context anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Using Karl's answer as inspiration, try using product and then taking advantage of the set object.  Something like,

```
set([set(comb) for comb in itertools.product(range(5),range(5)])
```

This will get rid of recurring pairs.  Then you can turn the set back into a list and sort it or iterate over it as you please.

EDIT:
this will actually kill the `x_m^2` terms, so build sorted tuples instead of sets.  this will allow the terms to be hashable and nonrepeating.

```
set([tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in itertools.product(range(5),range(5))])
```

Comment: you can't put sets into sets. you'd have to use frozensets so they are hashable